# React - How do I get the values of the total rewards by customer to calculate correctly?

Tags: reactjs

It's calculating the rewards correctly, except for the totalRewardsByCustomer.  The console logs that I've put in show that each time it goes thru the rewards, the totalRewardsByCustomer are resetting to zero.  What renders is the last received reward amount.  I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  Here is my code:

```
  let byCustomer = {};
  let totalRewardPointsByCustomer = {};
  
  rewardPointsPerTransaction.forEach(rewardPointsPerTransaction => {
    let {id, name, month, rewardPoints} = rewardPointsPerTransaction; 
      
    if (!byCustomer[id]) {
      byCustomer[id] = [];      
    } 
  
     if (!totalRewardPointsByCustomer[id]) {
      totalRewardPointsByCustomer[name] = 0;
      console.log(totalRewardPointsByCustomer)
    }
  
      totalRewardPointsByCustomer[name] += rewardPoints; 
       console.log(totalRewardPointsByCustomer)  
    
    if (byCustomer[id][month]) {
      byCustomer[id][month].rewardPoints += rewardPoints;
      byCustomer[id][month].monthNumber = month;
      byCustomer[id][month].numTransactions++;      
    }
    else {
      
      byCustomer[id][month] = {
        id,
        name,
        monthNumber:month,
        month: months[month],
        numTransactions: 1,        
        rewardPoints
      }
    }    
  });
  let tot = [];
  for (var custKey in byCustomer) {    
    byCustomer[custKey].forEach(cRow=> {
      tot.push(cRow);
    });    
  }
  
  let totByCustomer = [];
  for (custKey in totalRewardPointsByCustomer) {    
    totByCustomer.push({
      name: custKey,
      rewardPoints: totalRewardPointsByCustomer[custKey]
    });    
  }
  return {
    summaryByCustomer: tot,
    rewardPointsPerTransaction,
    totalRewardPointsByCustomer:totByCustomer
  };
}
```

Comment: One time you access it with id and sometimes with name, can you check that?

Comment: I've tried just accessing it by id or just accessing it by name, but nothing is working

Comment: Try to change it to  if (!totalRewardPointsByCustomer[name]) {

Comment: Thanks!  That worked!  I just wasn't trying it correctly before.  Post it as an answer, so that I can upvote your answer.